# How do I solve the 'No Element Exception' when using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Python to automate the process of taking bookings from my company's booking engine and organizing them into a daily schedule (the booking engine has it's own feature for exporting to a table in excel but the format you get isn't great so we still have to spend a good bit of time organizing into a format that's actually practical for us to use).

I have the program logging into the booking engine and navigating to the bookings page no problem, but I am stuck at getting it to navigate to a specific date. I have the user select the date they want to get the schedule for, at which point the program logs into the booking engine, goes to the bookings page and navigates to the date they selected.

Currently, I'm trying to get it to do this by calculating the how many days are between the current date and the date they select and clicking the 'next' button that many times. So let's say they pick the date of the same day next week it should click the next button 7 times.

Problem is, every time I get to that point, I get a 'no such element' error. I have tried copying the XPATH both using the 'inspect' function of Chrome and the Selectors Hub plugin. Same error. I have also tried finding the element by Class Name instead with the same result. The element ID is blank. I'm at a loss for how to get it to click this element.

**Element I'm trying to click:**
[image]

**Relevant code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = wd.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.webbymcwebsite.com')

email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div[2]/div/form/label[1]/input')
email.send_keys('SomeLoginDetails')

passwrd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/form/label[2]/input')
passwrd.send_keys('MoreLoginDetails')


    
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/form/button')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(3)

venue_manager = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-launchpad/div[2]/div/div/app-link[1]/button')
venue_manager.click()
time.sleep(5)

# THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING ISSES
next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/roller-data-filters/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]')
```

Comment: Without seeing the full html of the page, there's no way for us to say exactly how that xpath is wrong.